# Expression/phrase for "I'm working on it"

Tags: translation, phrase-request

Is there an expression that means "I'm working on it", translated inexpertly by me as "Sto lavorando su di esso", that stands in generality? Or do you alter the statement to match the object that is being worked on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd simply say “*ci sto lavorando*”, where this *ci* is a particle meaning – in this case – something like “on it, about it” (as in “*ci penso io*”, or “*che ci vuole?*”; see meaning 4 in [Treccani's article](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ci1/)).

Comment: 'ci sto lavorando *su*' è più aderente.